# What does the FCC do with confiscated equipment?

Tags: fcc

When a station is repeatedly violating FCC rules, transmitting out of band etc, equipment may be confiscated in addition to the fine. I am sure they have collected a large chunk of inventory from violating hams, pirate radio stations, kilowatt CB etc.

What does the FCC do with this equipment after confiscated? Is it for sale?

Answer (score 4):

FCC Special Counsel Laura Smith had a speech at Pacificon, a ham conference in the San Francisco area, last October. She said, after the case is closed and the equipment is confiscated they demolish it.

She further stated that they will try to change procedure to actually donate or auction the equipment instead.

See whole speech at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k08DClez1aQ&feature=youtu.be&t=24m38s

Comment: I do not see why not equipment be donated to some organizations or sold if it is usable. Drugs are different story, probably guns too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if there is an administrative action pending against an amateur from whom equipment has been seized, that equipment is held in escrow until the case is resolved (resolved meaning a final determination is ordered and the amateur has exhausted all available appeals). Once the case is resolved in favor of the government and the equipment is formally seized, it is liquidated at auction through the GSA.

Comment: This is an interesting question and an interesting answer.  Do you have any sources?

Comment: Thanks, do you know where these auctions take place?

Comment: This is interesting because the FCC says always said they destroy the equipment. Do you have any reference or documentation that shows this is the case?

Comment: They only destroy equipment that is not type certified. For example, illegally imported amplifiers and radios, home-built radios, and other devices that are not typically available at retail.

The government is not allowed to destroy property that has a lawful purpose or is otherwise lawful to own in the US. This is why the TSA auctions off literally tons of pocket knives every month.